# What is faster way to count relation?

Tags: database, sails.js, waterline

I'm using Waterline which is amazing ORM of Node.js. I think there are two ways to count relation(association).

First way is to apply record count when a relation record added or removed. e.g) A comment appended to a post, post's comment count field will be increased.

Second way is using 'count' query. I can count the relations when I need.

What I am worry is second way is easier but it seems to be slower than first way. It can request too much. But first way needs more dirty codes.

I really don't know what is best way to count relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to this question **have to be a little opinonated**, but I will give you my point of view.

**I would go with the "count query" solution** because it is the most reliable way to get this information. As you said, the other solution needs more dirty code and could be more easily bugged. I always try to have a single way to retrieve an information.

If the request is too much slow and/or too much frequent and slows down your application, then **you should consider caching the result**. Depending on the infrastructure you are using, you could cache the result of the query in a variable or in a fast cache backend like `memcached` or `Redis`. You will have to invalidate the cache when needed and it is up to you to decide the lifetime of the cache. You should define a global cache stategy of your application so you could use it for other parts of your application.

Comment: Sorry, it's too late! Thank you for answering!

Comment: Can every count result be stored for all posts' views, likes, scraps? I didn't know fast cache backend with Redis. I'll googling it but can you give me some clues?

Comment: I don't have much time to update the answer now,  but maybe you can have a look at [this module](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager/blob/master/README.md) or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)